# Angular 4: Router not redirecting

Tags: angular, routes, router

I have problems with navigation in my angular application. When I hit login, it's logging in, but its not redirecting to the chat page.

This is route.ts

```
import ...

export const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'signup', component: SignupFormComponent},
  { path: 'login', component: LoginFormComponent},
  { path: 'chat', component: ChatroomComponent},
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full'},
];
```

This is app.module.ts

```
imports: [
RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
],
```

And login-form.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
...
})
export class LoginFormComponent{
 email: string;
 password: string;
 errorMsg: string;

constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) { }

login() {
 this.authService.login(this.email, this.password)
 .then(resolve => this.router.navigate(['/chat']))
 .catch(error => this.errorMsg = error.message);
 }
}
```

[image: Fist]

[image: When login]

Comment: do you get any error in the browser console? if yes could you post that also?

Comment: What does your authService code for `login` look like? Perhaps its logging in, but not resolving your promise?

Comment: This is authService for login:
  
login(email: string, password: string) {
    return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then((resolve) => {
        const status = 'online';
        this.setUserStatus(status);
        this.router.navigate(['chat']);
      });
  }

Comment: browser console also no error when i hit login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment:

```
login(email: string, password: string) { 
     return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then((resolve) => { 
      const status = 'online'; this.setUserStatus(status); 
      this.router.navigate(['chat']); 
  }); 
}
```

The line `this.router.navigate(['chat']);` is potentially blocking the promise from resolving to your components login (as `router` is blocked with an invalid route.)

Either, take that line out of the `authService` function, and allow the components `login` resolution to deal with it, or, remember to add the slash before `chat` in the `authService version.

```
 this.router.navigate(['/chat']);
```

Comment: Also, `const status = 'online'; this.setUserStatus(status); ` is pretty redundant, what's wrong with `this.setUserStatus('online')`.... uses one less assignment. May be small but these things add up :)

Comment: Yup. I set

 .then ((resolve) => {
         this.router.navigate (['/ chat']);
const status = 'online';
         this.setUserStatus (status);});      

It worked!!!
I solved this problem, thank you.